# Getting words to the left and right of a certain group of words using preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get the text to the left and right of a certain group of words using preg_match_all, but it's not working the way I thought it would. Instead print_r printing out the array that holds the text to the left and right of the certain group of words, it's printing out nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
$input = "text1 can you text2";
preg_match_all('(.+?)\s+can you\s+(.+)/i', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
$input = "text1 can you text2";

$x=explode('can you',$input);
print_r($x); //Array ( [0] => text1 [1] => text2 )
```

Comment: I have a major urge to facepalm at myself and go "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.";